# How Can I Start Java API (backend)

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, api, server

How Can I start a java API (backend)

I need to install maven or another program?

the backend has mongodb as database.

I just want to start it and show the data in a Angular Application.

example in nodejs:

npm install
npm start

Comment: You mentioned the backend is a Spring Boot application. Are you able to build the application? If so you should be able to just run the jar. Otherwise, see if you can find a pom.xml file (for maven) or a build.gradle file (for gradle). If you have one of those, you will need to install the matching build tool to build and start the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to deploy a REST controller that will serve the data to your application: here is a [good tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web). Note that this example is built with a trivial repository, with hard-coded data.

Then, you must adapt the repository to read data from [mongo db](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/).

Answer (score 0):

You can learn spring boot for API.

Comment: API is in spring boot, but I dont know how to start the service

Comment: Without guarantee:  java -jar mySpringBootApp.jar